# Update one column where another column within same table equals a column in another table

Tags: sql

I have a Query for retrieving data from one table where one column equals one specific value and one column equals a column in another table.

Like this:

```
SELECT a.IdOrdre, b.FR_Ordre 
FROM Ordre a 
INNER JOIN OrdreKategori b ON a.IdOrdre=b.FR_Ordre 
WHERE b.FR_Kategori=57
```

I now would like to update the column `FR_Kategori` to another value than `57`. How would I structure the `UPDATE` Query in order to achieve this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't tag your DBMS, and every one has different syntax for `UPDATE..JOIN` , here is an ANSI-SQL answer:

```
UPDATE OrdreKategori t
SET t.fr_kategori = Other_Val
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Ordre s
             where s.IdOrdre=t.FR_Ordre)
  AND t.fr_kategori = 57
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for Your reply. The server is a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3156.0 (X64)

Comment: Doesn't matter @AndrasLindqvist This should work for any product.

Comment: This gives the following Message: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 't'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: This works though: UPDATE OrdreKategori SET OrdreKategori.FR_Kategori = 5 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Ordre WHERE Ordre.IdOrdre=OrdreKategori.FR_Ordre) AND OrdreKategori.FR_Kategori = 57